# What's the difference between location vs desktoplocation in win form?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

What's the difference between location vs desktoplocation in windows form ?
It looks like that both of them can locate form.
Then what is the difference ?

Comment: One refers to the screen it is on, the other to the desktop. Only if the desktop spans several screens it will be able make a difference..

Comment: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/msdn.microsoft.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on where the taskbar is docked, `Location` and `DesktopLocation` may or may not refer to the same location.

`DesktopLocation` is always relative to the desktop itself, which may vary depending on where the taskbar is located, and whether it is "always on top" or not.

Sp, if the taskbar is located at the top of the screen and set to "always on top", `DesktopLocation = 0,0` refers to the same point as `Location = 0, Taskbar.Height`.

Similarly, when the Taskbar is docked on the left-hand side, `DesktopLocation = 0,0` refers to `Location = Taskbar.Width, 0`

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer. But I'm not clear yet. If we change this.Location value, the form position is changed.What happen if we change this.DesktopLocation in the code during runtime ?(I tried it for myself and there is no change at all.)

Comment: If I set `someform.DesktopLocation = new Point(0,0)` or call `someform.SetDesktopLocation(0,0)`, the `someform` form changes its position to 0,0 on the current screen immediately. Could you post your non-working code in an update to your question (or a new question)?